# What version of scikit learn is compatible with 0.20.3

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

My goal is to upgrade scikit-learn to the latest version possible,
but upgrading from 0.20.3 to 0.24.0(latest) breaks my models.

Does anyone know how to figure out discrepancies in scikit learn package
organization/have any prior knowledge?

The errors I'm seeing are as follows when unpickling my models.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model.logistic'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.gradient_boosting'
```

Comment: have you had any updates on this issue?